# Question about spread argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash, spread-syntax

This is my code.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function test(num1: number, num2: number) {
    console.log(num1, num2);
}

test(..._.take(_.shuffle([0, 1, 2]), 2));
```

I got a `TS2556` error on the TS playground and VSCode.

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. (ts2556)

I got a `TS2556` error on repl.it site as well.

> error TS2556: Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.

I have no idea how I can resolve this.

Comment: Problem is that `_.take`'s return type is `number[]`.. You could add type assertion: `test(..._.take(_.shuffle([0, 1, 2]), 2) as [number, number]);`

Comment: Great!! It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator should be used when you expect, as the error points out, **0 or more parameters**. Since your function expects exactly 2 parameters, no more, no less, then it would make more sense to write

```
const myArray = _.take(_.shuffle([0, 1, 2]), 2);

test(myArray[0], myArray[1]);
```

Be sure to add a check just in case (especially if you don't know what the array contains that you pass to shuffle) by checking whether it does contain these two values if you don't want to have a runtime error.

A valid use case for rest parameters:

```
const myFunction = (requiredParameter: number, ...someOtherOptionalParams: number[]) => {
  someOtherOptionalParams.map(param => {
    // do something with optional params, if any
  })
}
```

Your code would work, too, if both parameters were optional:

```
function test(num1?: number, num2?: number) {
    console.log(num1, num2);
}
```

That is, the function would take the first two values of your array, if any and would do something with them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is more clean code. Because I used magic numbers, I thought two numbers would be entered for sure.